# How to change the tabs in react native application using native base components

Tags: button, react-native, tabs, native-base

i have a main screen that contains 2 Tabs in which every one renders different result.
At the end of the the first tabs, i have two buttons that :             First Button --> redirect to  First Tab year 1 (the default tab)
Second Button --> redirect to First Tab Version Two  year 2 
So, basically the buttons redirect to different Tab every time selected . I need to only change the tab not the whole screen. 
here is the code that i used and it's working fine for the default Tab but i don't know how to implement the buttons so that it redirects to different tabs with changing the main screen ... Any help ?

Main screen :

```
<Tabs>
    <Tab heading="First Tab">
        <FirstTab text={key} />
    </Tab>
    <Tab heading="Second Tab">
        <SecondTab/>
    </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

the First Tab (the default one)

```
<ScrollView>
                ...
                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                        <Button active>
                            <Text>
                                year 1 
                            </Text>
                        </Button>
                        <Button>
                            <Text> year 2  </Text>
                        </Button>
                    </View>
                </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is an image that explains what i need to do : 
[image]

I also tried this method: [Implementing Footer Tabs in Native React using Native Base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095875/implementing-footer-tabs-in-native-react-using-native-base) and the code i used is :

```
<Tabs>
    <Tab>
        <Content>{this.renderSelectedTab()} </Content>
    </Tab>
    <Tab>
        <SecondTab/>
    </Tab>
</Tabs>
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <Button active={this.selectedTab==='2016'}
            onPress={() => this.state.setState({selectedTab: '2016'})}>
                  <Text> 2016 </Text>
    </Button>

    <Button active={this.state.selectedTab==='2015'}
            onPress={() => this.setState({selectedTab: '2015'})} >
                <Text> 2015 </Text>
    </Button>
</View>
```

..

```
renderSelectedTab () {
   console.log("this.state.selectedTab", this.selectedTab )
        switch (this.state.selectedTab) {
            case '2016':
                return (<Tab2016 />);
                break;
            case '2015':
                return (<Tab2015 />);
                break;
            default:
                return (<Tab2016 />);
        }
    }
```

And i get [image]

If i use **this.selectedTab** instead of **this.state.selectedTab** it runs fine but i get in the console : [image] and it runs directly the default value and the buttons don't work

Comment: have you binded the renderSelectedTab function inside constructor?

Comment: hi , i just solved my problem thank you .. but i'm stuck on how to change the style of a button when pressed .. and i will post the complete answer when finishing it

Comment: this will useful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34625829/change-button-style-on-press-in-react-native?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @user3521011 Did you solve it?

Comment: hey @SupriyaKalghatgi i solved it  partially **but** still didn't figure out how to change the **style of the button when pressed** or not .. i couldn't find anything  in the official documentation of native base or in any other source actually .. Do you have any idea how to do it ? thanks for your help

Comment: @user3521011 Try adding `onFocus` prop in the theme and style for the same

Answer (score 3):

Actually, that is not how it works.
You need to use **the page and initialPage props of Tabs Component** and then to change tabs you only need to **update the page props to the tab index**

So that is an example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Content, Tab, Tabs } from 'native-base';

export default class AuthScreenContent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {activeTab: 0, initialTab: 0}
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Container>
          <Tabs initialPage={this.state.initialTab} page={this.state.activeTab}>
            <Tab heading="Sign up">
              <Text>This is the register's content </Text>
              <Button
                  title="Go to login tab"
                  onPress={() => this.setState({activeTab: 1})}
              />
            </Tab>
            <Tab heading="Login">
              <Text>This is the login's content </Text>
              <Button
                  title="Go to register tab"
                  onPress={() => this.setState({activeTab: 0})}
              />
            </Tab>
          </Tabs>
        </Container>
    );
  }
};
```